# Too many arguments to return in Go program

Tags: go

I have made this simple software to connect to AWS and generate a presigned put url:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

// AWS contains the configuration to connect and create a presigned url on AWS.
type AWS struct {
  Endpoint        string
  AccessKeyId     string
  SecretAccessKey string
  SSL             bool
  BucketHost      string
  BucketKey       string
}

func main() {
    url, err = generatePresignedPutUrl()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(url)
}

func generatePresignedPutUrl() {
    var aws AWS
    if err := envconfig.Process("aws", &aws); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    svc, err := minio.New(aws.Endpoint, aws.AccessKeyId, aws.SecretAccessKey, aws.SSL)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    url, err := svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)
    if err != nil {
        return url, err
    }
}
```

But when I try to run `go run main.go`, the following errors show in my terminal:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:23:5: undefined: url
./main.go:23:10: undefined: err
./main.go:23:39: generatePresignedPutUrl() used as value
./main.go:24:8: undefined: err
./main.go:25:19: undefined: err
./main.go:27:17: undefined: url
./main.go:33:9: too many arguments to return
    have (error)
    want ()
./main.go:38:9: too many arguments to return
    have (error)
    want ()
./main.go:43:9: too many arguments to return
    have (*url.URL, error)
    want ()
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I started to learn go a few days ago. I'm sorry if this is to much obvious.

---

Update:

I was able to figure it out that I should declare what I'm returning from `generatePresignedPutUrl`, but still:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go"
    "github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig"
)

// AWS contains the configuration to connect and create a pre-signed url on AWS.
type AWS struct {
  Endpoint        string
  AccessKeyId     string
  SecretAccessKey string
  SSL             bool
  BucketHost      string
  BucketKey       string
}

func main() {
    url, err := generatePresignedPutUrl()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(url)
}

// generatePresignedPutUrl connects to S3 and generates a pre-signed put url
// using configurations from environemnt variables.
func generatePresignedPutUrl() (url string, err error) {
    var aws AWS
    if err := envconfig.Process("aws", &aws); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    svc, err := minio.New(aws.Endpoint, aws.AccessKeyId, aws.SecretAccessKey, aws.SSL)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    url, err := svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)
    if err != nil {
        return url, err
    }

    return url
}
```

Errors:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:36:9: not enough arguments to return
    have (error)
    want (string, error)
./main.go:41:9: not enough arguments to return
    have (error)
    want (string, error)
./main.go:44:14: no new variables on left side of :=
./main.go:44:14: cannot assign *url.URL to url (type string) in multiple assignment
./main.go:49:5: not enough arguments to return
    have (string)
    want (string, error)
```

Comment: You can't return values if your function doesn't declare any return values. Try starting with the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Comment: Yeah, I figure it out before you comment, but still, isn't clear what to put as the first value of the generatePresignedPutUrl. Could you check my updates?

Comment: It says in the error message: `cannot assign *url.URL to url (type string)` -- you have a `*url.URL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, you should really do the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) as JimB said. It takes less than an hour and you would know the answer to this questions.

Notice that you are declaring `url` and `err` on the return declaration of `generatePresignedPutUrl()` and it doesn't look like that was what you wanted to do. You should change the function declaration from:

```
func generatePresignedPutUrl() (url string, err error) {
```

To:

```
func generatePresignedPutUrl() (string, error) { // Without the variable names
```

Now lets address your errors in order:

**Error 1: not enough arguments to return**

Error is Go are not really cryptic. `not enough arguments to return` means literally what it says. You are trying to return less arguments than the ones you should.

In Go you can return more than one value from a function but no matter how much values you return, you always need to return all the values. Your function `func generatePresignedPutUrl() (url string, err error)` expects a `string` and an `error` but in `return err` you are just returning `err` which is of type `error` so you are missing a `string`, in this case because there was an error in the function return an empty string. To fix it just do: `return "", err` instead.

**Error 2: no new variables on left side of :=**

Again not really cryptic. It means none of the variables on the left of `:=` are new. The `:=` declares a new variable and then assigns the value to that variable, so if the variable isn't new you get an error when trying to declare it. In this case you declared `url` on the function declaration and `err` on the second line of the function. To fix it replace:

```
url, err := svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

For:

```
url, err = svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

**Error 3: cannot assign *url.URL to url (type string) in multiple assignment**

You are trying to assign a type `*url.URL` to the variable `url` which is a `string`. In Go you can only assign something to a variable if they are from the same type. [Here](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL) are the docs for the url.URL type. To fix it do:

```
rawUrl, err := svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}

return rawUrl.String() // rawUrl is of type *url.URL, so get it's string representation
```

Answer (score 0):

From the godoc of [github.com/minio-go](https://godoc.org/github.com/minio/minio-go), [Client.PresignedPutObject](https://godoc.org/github.com/minio/minio-go#Client.PresignedPutObject). returns a [*url.URL](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL) and an `error`

(i.e. `url, err := svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)` )

From your code, you probably want the url string right?

If that's what you want, you can refer to this example from the godoc of [*url.URL](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL):

Also, you can't just return an error from your function, `you have to return a string and an error`.

Modifying your code to return a url string, you can probably do something like this:

```
func generatePresignedPutUrl() (url string, err error) {
    var aws AWS
    if err := envconfig.Process("aws", &aws); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    svc, err := minio.New(aws.Endpoint, aws.AccessKeyId, aws.SecretAccessKey, aws.SSL)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    u, err := svc.PresignedPutObject(aws.BucketHost, aws.BucketKey, time.Second * 24 * 60 * 60)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    url = u.String()
    return url, err
}
```